# DataGridViewCheckboxCell making new row when checked for some reason

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I have an application in VB 2008 Express that uses a DataGridView to display rows of information. I have a DataGridViewCheckboxCell on each row for selecting the row so the user can mass delete the selected rows. For some reason, whenever I try to select a row via checkbox it adds another row to the DataGridView, is there anyway to disable this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to set `AllowUserToAddRows = False` on the `DataGridView`.